# ERROR in jQuery is not defined webpack and imports-loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, imports-loader

I got this error when I tried to add a jquery library.

```
{
   test: require("path").resolve("./main/static/src/application.js"),
   loader: 'imports-loader?this=>window,$=jquery!./main/static/src/vendor/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js'
}

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    io: 'socket.io-client',
    _:'underscore',
    moment:"moment",
})
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR in jQuery is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few ways to resolve this, I opted for the [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/):

```
{
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [
   'expose-loader?jQuery',
   'expose-loader?$'
  ]
},
```

[See more details.](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-part-3-finish-the-vendors/)

Comment: Double check that you are using an uppercase Q. It should read "jQuery", your snippets show "jquery"